# JDBC - csv file Error

Tags: java, csv, jdbc, connection

I have a simple question, somehow I can't see where my problem is.

I've got a csv file in my C:/Temp folder. I would like to connect to the csv to get some data (depending on specific row data, different rows,...).

So I downloaded the csvjdbc-1.0-28.jar file and added it to the build path. 
I wrote the code as shown below but always get the error: 
"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for"

I have seen some people got also problems with it but I did not get the problem behind the issue I have. I know it has something to do with the Connection conn. Do I need to do some additional JDBC settings or how can I add the path for the connection?

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver;

public class Main_Class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            try {
                Class.forName("org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("c:\\temp\\Spieltage_log.txt");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet results = stmt
                        .executeQuery("select * from Offensiver_Zweikampf");
                boolean append = true;
                CsvDriver.writeToCsv(results, System.out, append);
                conn.close();
                System.out.println(results);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // JFrame fenster = new Main_Menue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example at (http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/)-

```
 // Create a connection. The first command line parameter is
  // the directory containing the .csv files.
  // A single connection is thread-safe for use by several threads.
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:" + directoryName);
```

In your case it should be  -

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("fileExtension", ".txt");

  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:C:\\temp", props);
```

Also you've put the content in a txt file, so you'll need to specify a custom property with the fileExtension as '.txt' in it.

Your resultSet object than can query the file using the below syntax -

```
ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Spieltage_log");
```

Comment: Connecting the txt file works fine, but with a csv file I still get an error (File not found even if it's there...

Answer (score 1):

The URL string passed to `DriverManager.getConnection()` needs to specify the driver name:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:c:\\temp");
```

Besides, you need to pass the directory of the csv file and not the file itself. See answer of Sachin who in the meantime posted detailed instructions.

Comment: I see, but now I get the error that the Directory has not been found: java.sql.SQLException: Directory not found: c:\temp\Spieltage_log.txt\ - But the folder is definitely there. In a different class I point to it....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my fault: I saved the file as a xlsx file and not csv file. So solved it now and it worked! Thanks a lot guys! Appreciate your help